# How to catch an error in batch file running inside python script

Tags: python, batch-file, error-handling

I have Python script that calls several batch files through os.system. However, sometimes the batch file will throw errors and exit via `exit /b 1`.

However, even though the batch script fails, the Python script continues running, but I'd like the entire python script to quit as well if any batch script throws an error. How do I catch this exception in Python?

Comment: Why are you using `os()` instead of `subprocess()`?

Comment: The usage of [os.system](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) is deprecated since Python 3.0 which is for more than 10 years now. It exists only for compatibility with old Python 2.x scripts. That function should not be used anymore in newly written Python scripts using Python 3.x. There is the [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html).

Comment: The `subprocess` module gives a Python programmer the full control on how the Windows kernel library function [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) is called to run an executable while `os.system()` results in calling `CreateProcess` to run `%ComSpec% /c ...` which means the *Windows Command Processor* `cmd.exe` which uses also `CreateProcess` to run executables. The roundabout route via `cmd.exe` is completely unnecessary in every Python 3.x script. Please do not use the suggested solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`os.system`'s return value is (usually. There are some caveats so you should check out the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system)).

It can be used to catch the `exit 1` in the batch script:

```py
import os

exit_code = os.system('./some_batch_script')

if exit_code != 0:
    raise Exception(f'batch script exited with {exit_code}')
```